# Projections in Graph Products

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I was going throug the topic ***Projections in Graph Products***. There a term ***weak homomorphism*** was used. Although I am familiar with the term *Isomorphism of graphs*, but have no idea what this term "weak homomorphism" means here.

**PROJECTION:** Let * represent either cartesian, the direct or strong product of graphs, and consider a product $G_1 * G_2* ....*G_k$. For any index *i* 1$\leq$*i*$\leq$*k*, a *Projection* map is defined as :

$p_i$ : $G_1 * G_2* ....*G_k$ $\rightarrow$ $G_i$ where $p_i$($x_1,x_2,...,x_k$)=$x_i$.

Can anybody help me out with the term ***weak homomorphism***.

Thanks a lot.

Following links will help for definiton of product graphs...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(We don’t actually need to know about the graph products in order to answer the question.)

If $G$ and $H$ are graphs with vertex sets $V(G)$ and $V(H)$, respectively, a *homomorphism* from $G$ to $H$ is a map $\varphi:V(G)\to V(H)$ that preserves adjacency: if $uv$ is an edge in $G$, then $\varphi(u)\varphi(v)$ is an edge in $H$. A *weak homomorphism* from $G$ to $H$ is a map $\varphi:V(G)\to V(H)$ such that if $uv$ is an edge in $G$, then either $\varphi(u)\varphi(v)$ is an edge in $H$, or $\varphi(u)=\varphi(v)$. In other words, if $\varphi$ is a weak homomorphism from $G$ to $H$, and $e$ is an edge in $G$, $\varphi$ either preserves $e$ as an edge by collapses it to a single vertex. Clearly every homomorphism is automatically a weak homomorphism.

In the diagram below let $G$ be the path graph on the left and $H$ the triangle graph on the right.

```
           1---2---3                a---b  
                                     \ /  
                                      c
```

The map

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
1&\mapsto a\\
2&\mapsto b\\
3&\mapsto c
\end{align*}\right.$$

is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a homomorphism. The map

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
1&\mapsto a\\
2&\mapsto b\\
3&\mapsto b
\end{align*}\right.$$

is not a homomorphism, because it does not take the edge $23$ of $G$ to an edge of $H$, but it is a weak homomorphism: it collapses that edge to the single vertex $b$ of $H$.

Comment: Nicely explained ... :-) I got my doubts cleared now. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @monalisa: You’re welcome.